# Use an huge image as a sprite

Tags: iphone, sdk, lua, coronasdk, sprite

I'd like to use an huge image as a sprite in my game made with corona SDK. The image dimensions are 4172x320, for a total of 28 frames.

The fact is that when I load the scene that contains this image, the physics engine turns off. I read that the dimensions limits for a sprite is set to 2048x2048 and in fact it works as it should, but I lost the smoothness that 28 frames give to the sprite.

The code I've used to declare the spritesheet is:

```
local sheet2 = graphics.newImageSheet( "immagini/profDonnaCOMP.png", { width=149, height=320,      numFrames=28 } )
    local instance2 = display.newSprite( sheet2, { name="profDonna", start=1, count=28, time=800 } )
    instance2.x = _W/2
    instance2.y = _H/2+150
    instance2.myName = "instance2"
    instance2:play()
    physics.addBody( instance2, "dynamic", { friction=0.5, bounce=0 } )
```

What can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Hi try making other sprite which will be 7x4 instead of 28x1 and you will get 1043x960 image which is good to go.

Comment: Yeah I think I'm gonna do that. Thanks.